# why does the code print the "test message" although I wrote just the code for printing the attribute "a"

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, module

I don't know why it prints both "test message" and "ABC" instead of just "ABC".
I think just wrote the code for printing the attribute "a" but it prints something more!

I have two modules: "first.py" & "second.py"

first.py is:

```py
import second
print(second.a)
```

second.py is:

```py
a="ABC"
print("test message")
```

OUTPUT is:

```py
test message
ABC
```

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, everything at the top level of a python module is executed on import. What is your goal for the print? Do you want second.py to run as a script, printing something, and run as an imported module, not printing something?

Comment: this question occurred during studying the python documentation. so this is not part of a project. so I don't have any special goal for printing like this.
I just wanted that print attribute "a" without printing the message.
of course, I understood the reason for the problem,
thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import second` will run all code in `second.py`.
`print("test message")` is also executed.
If you want to prevent this use below

```
a = 'ABC'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("test message")
```

`if __name__ == "__main__":` will only run when run from that file.